# text-shadow circular debajo del texto

Tags: css, css3

Estoy tratando de crear de manera circular la sombra de un texto de fondo, pero no he logrado conseguirlo, solo he podido la sombra normal. A continuación, dejare un ejemplo de lo que trato de conseguir

[image: shadow]

Solo consigo esto

https://jsfiddle.net/f24xgp4u/43/

Comment: las sombras son un reflejo en cada lado? por lo que veo en el corazón, tiene uno morado a la derecha y un verde  agua a la derecha? o lo que te importa es la sombra en forma circular?

Comment: eso mismo concluí después de echar una buena vista

Answer (score 1):

Con **text-shadow** deverías conseguir lo que propones. Yo he probado con esto para tener una doble sombra a cada lado. Espero que el resultado sea lo que te propones

```css
h1 {
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: -20px 0px 7px red, 20px 0px 7px blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>V</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr ese "círculo" debes realizar un difuminado más amplio.

**Ejemplo**

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffdf;
}
h2 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: -15px 0px 20px #FF00FF,
    15px 0px 20px #00bbff;
}
```

```html
<h2>❤</h2>
<h2>♕ MSW ♕</h2>
```